# Given String, print same characters on same line, different character on next line using c++?

Tags: c++, string

I have the input as "AABBABCCCDDDDE" or any other string as similar kind, i want the output as

```
AA
BB
A
B
CCC
DDDD
E
```

i.e. if the current and next character and if any more characters are same, print the characters on the same line, or else print the next character on the next line.

I have written this below code,

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char str[] = "AABBABCCCDDDDE" ;

   int i = 0 ;

   while(str[i] != '\0') {

      if(str[i] == str[i+1]) {

         cout << str[i] << str[i+1] << '\n' ;

         i++ ;

         } else {

               cout << str[i] << '\n' ; 
               }

         i++ ;

     } 

   return 0;
}
```

but i am getting the output as,

```
AA
BB
A
B
CC
C
DD
DD
E
```

I need to do some modifications to the above to get the correct output, suggestions needed.
Also, it would be good if anyone can suggest the most efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: Whatever the if statement evaluates to, a new line is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want every character to be printed at some point, put code for that *outside* of the `if`. Then, the `if` can just test for whether or not a newline is needed:

```
while(str[i] != '\0') {
  // Print the current character
  cout << str[i];

  // If the next character is different, print a newline.
  if (str[i] != str[i+1])
    cout << '\n';

  ++i;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

in this line:

```
if(str[i] == str[i+1]) {

     cout << str[i] << str[i+1] << '\n' ;    //this one

     i++ ;

     }
```

remove the '\n'
edit: and the `str[i+1]` to avoid printing duplicates

Comment: This isn't enough to make the OP's code work correctly. It needs to be `if(str[i] == str[i+1]) { cout << str[i]; }`. That is, remove the `'\n'`, the `str[i+1]` and the `i++`. Then it should work.

Comment: sorry my bad, I didn't read it carefully so I didn't notice it